# Why can I checkout a deleted Git branch, and why is it still available on GitHub?

Tags: git, git-branch

At the beginning, I have only the *master* branch.

Then I create a new branch with the following command:

```
git branch 'branch1'
```

Then I add some file to branch1 and merge it to master. Then I execute the following command to delete the *branch1*.

```
git branch -d branch1
```

Then locally, I can only see master branch now. But on GitHub, I can still see the branch1 in the branch list.

And I can still checkout the branch1 though I deleted it.

Why?

Comment: You are long enough here for being able to learn how question titles should look like ... "Question about Git branch" is not a good title (as it says about nothing about the content). (I edited your title to what I think your question is about, feel free to edit again.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're the only person using this GitHub repository, you *must* have pushed `branch1` to it at some point, probably with `git push origin branch1` or something similar.

As [Alexander says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172219/question-about-git-branch/7172266#7172266) you can remove the branch `branch1` from GitHub with:

```
git push origin :branch1
```

... but then to remove your remote-tracking branch `origin/branch1` you should do:

```
git remote prune origin
```

The interesting thing here is that you could still checkout `branch1`, presumably with:

```
git checkout branch1
```

... even when you'd deleted the local branch.  It turns out that this is because, since v1.6.6, git will try to guess what you mean when you try to checkout a non-existent branch, but exactly one remote-tracking branch with a matching name exists.  That's introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c9ac2f1999b7e0c17a864235537cffe29dfea4) by the git maintainer, Junio C Hamano:

> DWIM "git checkout frotz" to "git checkout -b frotz origin/frotz"
>
> When 'frotz' is not a valid object name and not a tracked filename,
>   we used to complain and failed this command.  When there is only
>   one remote that has 'frotz' as one of its tracking branches, we can
>   DWIM it as a request to create a local branch 'frotz' forking from
>   the matching remote tracking branch.

This is a bit of a surprise to me, and it's not mentioned in the `git checkout` man page.

Comment: It seems the process we take to learn something is the very process for us to adapt to it. Better or worse.

Comment: Just learn that if your remote branches are on upstream repo, you should do `git remote prune upstream` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you pushed the branch to github and `git branch -d BRANCHNAME` only deletes branches locally while the github pointer is left untouched. If you want to delete it on github as well, you can do `git push origin :BRANCHNAME` (notice the colon, and also this is assuming "origin" is your github repo which afaik is the default)

See [this](http://help.github.com/remotes/#deleting_a_remote_branch_or_tag) for a bit more info on the command.

Answer (score 1):

Branches in [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) are only pointers (references) into a tree of commits, and each repository has its own set of references. If "branch1" appears on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), it just means that there is a reference on GitHub called "branch1" which points into your tree (on GitHub) (it does even need to point to the same commit).